# How are return value from a createEffect are used

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, frontend, ngrx

I has going through a code and came across a code for createeffect which is returning a value.

I am unable to understand how the return value are used. Can somebody help me in understanding how return values are used?

```
fetchData$ = createEffect(
      () => this.actions$.pipe(
          ofType(actions.FETCH_DATA_ACTION),
          map(action => action.payload),
          exhaustMap((actionPayload) => {
              return actions.FETCH_LIVE_DATA_ACTION();
            } 
          }),
          ));
```

Comment: This is NgRx. This effect triggers when FETCH_DATA_ACTION is dispatched. Effects are like services that deal with side effects. Basically you're returning an observable that will emit the FETCH_LIVE_DATA_ACTION with the payload for the request, that request will be done by some service called when triggering FETCH_LIVE_DATA_ACTION

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is wrong, an `exhaustMap` should return an `Observable<Action>`, in your case it's just an Action.

NgRx effects returns to the results, and dispatches the emitted actions back to the store.

https://ngrx.io/guide/effects

Comment: I've seen implementations of NgRx with custom wrappers that use the returned action in dynamic reducers to trigger the services.